# Weird temporary files generated by docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, tmp

I have a server running multiple docker compose environments dynamically. Every while I find `/tmp` is full due to some writing there. So after inspection I found these files to be generated by docker-compose.

```
~/dias-docker-cli$ ll /tmp
total 332K
drwxrwxrwt 77 root    root    4.0K Nov 30 12:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root    root    4.0K Sep 10 12:59 ..
drwx------ 15 user user 4.0K Nov 22 14:52 _MEI0VowTd
drwx------ 15 user user 4.0K Nov 18 16:37 _MEI1lksr6
drwx------ 15 user user 4.0K Nov 19 13:19 _MEI2jQ7eV
drwx------ 15 user user 4.0K Nov 30 10:30 _MEI61I0ih
drwx------ 15 user user 4.0K Nov 25 12:16 _MEI6phtf4
drwx------ 15 user user 4.0K Nov 29 18:06 _MEI7S9myI
drwx------ 15 user user 4.0K Nov 19 12:06 _MEI7acyQ5
.
.
.
```

inside of each directory, there is a json file:

```
$ grep -R docker /tmp
/tmp/_MEI2jQ7eV/compose/config/compose_spec.json:                "dockerfile": {"type": "string"},
/tmp/_MEI2jQ7eV/compose/config/config_schema_v1.json:        "dockerfile": {"type": "string"},
/tmp/_MEI2jQ7eV/compose/config/config_schema_v1.json:              {"required": ["dockerfile"]}
.
.
.
```

What are these files and why they are stored there?